# Android CarouselPicker when 1st item is click

Tags: java, android, carousel

I found a library on github that has CarouselPicker **com.github.Vatican-Cameos:CarouselPicker:v1.0** i added this in the dependencies and compile also in repositories **maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'}**

I have successfully make a CarouselPicker this is the **JAVA CODE**

```
carouselPicker = (CarouselPicker)findViewById(R.id.carouselPicker);

    List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> itemsImage = new ArrayList<>();
    itemsImage.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.abc));
    itemsImage.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.123));
    itemsImage.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.colors));
    itemsImage.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.shapes));
    CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this, itemsImage,0);
    carouselPicker.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

And by having a LinearLayout this is the XML code

```
<in.goodiebag.carouselpicker.CarouselPicker
    android:id="@+id/carouselPicker"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:items_visible="three"
    />
```

I cant find on google on what if the 1st item in the carousel picker selected like a `OnClickListener`to change the `intent`

Answer (score 1):

I found a library you used on [this link](https://github.com/GoodieBag/CarouselPicker)
You must use `addOnPageChangeListener` like this:

```
carouselPicker.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //position of the selected item
            if(position == 0){
                startActivity(new Intent(thisActivity.this, anotherActivity1.class));
            }                
            else if(position == 1){
                startActivity(new Intent(thisActivity.this, anotherActivity2.class));
            } 
            // Same conditions for another cases.
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

So, your `onClickListener` that you want to handle the click event, is `onPageSelected` method.

Comment: imageAdapter.OnClickListener? or carouselPicker.OnClickLisnter ?

Comment: When you click any of your list item, it goes `onPageSelected` method. `int position` is your selected item's position. Did you try this solution ?

Comment: yes sir the using the position i can define which page is selected and showed but how when it is tapped or click? like they really want to select this and direct them to the other intent.. i could get the position.. but not the thing that is selected

Comment: its like inside `onPageSelected` if the page is click what code can i apply to change the intent?

Comment: Can you update your question with using this solution ?